# How to fix Property 'incrementCount' does not exist on type 'ContextType | undefined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, react-typescript

I am trying to abstract the logic of useContext and useReducer to not repeat the code whenever i create a new context but i ran in to some problems when i try to strongly type createContext with typescript.

With this function i automate context creation:

```
import React, { createContext, ReactElement, useReducer } from 'react';

type ProviderProps = {
    children: ReactElement;
};

type ActionType = {
  type: string;
    payload?: any;
};

export default function <StateType>(
    reducer: (state: StateType, action: ActionType) => StateType,
    actions: any,
    initialState: StateType,
) {
    type ContextType = {
        state: StateType;
        actions:{
            [k: string]: Function;
        }
    };
    const Context = React.createContext<ContextType | undefined>(undefined);

    const Provider = ({ children }: ProviderProps) => {
        const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

        const boundActions: any = {};

        for (let key in actions) {
            boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch);
        }
        return (
            <Context.Provider value={{ state, actions:{
                ...boundActions
            } }}>
                {children}
            </Context.Provider>
        );
    };

    return { Context, Provider };
}
```

Example context creation:

```
import createDataContext from './createDataContext';
import { INCRASE_COUNT, DECRASE_COUNT } from './ActionTypes';

type ActionType = {
    type: string;
    payload?: any;
};

type StateType = {
    count: number;
};

const reducer = (state: StateType, action: ActionType) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case INCRASE_COUNT:
            return { count: state.count + 1 };
        case DECRASE_COUNT:
            return { count: state.count - 1 };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const incrementCount = (dispatch: React.Dispatch<any>) => {
    return () => {
        dispatch({ type: INCRASE_COUNT });
    };
};

const decrementCount = (dispatch: React.Dispatch<any>) => {
    return () => {
        dispatch({ type: DECRASE_COUNT });
    };
};

export const { Context, Provider } = createDataContext<StateType>(
    reducer,
    {
        incrementCount,
        decrementCount,
    },
    { count: 69 },
);
```

When i use it:

```
import { Context as ExampleContext } from '../context/ExampleContext';

const { state, actions } = useContext(
    ExampleContext,
);
```

it underlines state and actions with a red line and says:
Property 'state, actions' does not exist on type 'ContextType | undefined'

What did i do wrong here is there something that i missed?

PLZZZZZZ HELP ME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error since you specified context type as `ContextType | undefined` and `undefined` does not have `state` and `actions` properties.
Instead of passing `undefined` to `createContext` you can refactor your code like this:

```
export default function <StateType>(
    reducer: (state: StateType, action: ActionType) => StateType,
    actions: any,
    initialState: StateType,
) {
    type ContextType = {
        state: StateType;
        actions: typeof actions;
    };
    
    const Context = React.createContext<ContextType>({
      state: initialState,
      actions,
    });
    
    ...

    return { Context, Provider };
}
```

Comment: No sir this wont work because 'state' is not always going to be { count: 0}, it can be anything that is why i put StateType as a generic so state type can be dynamic

Comment: Why don't you pass the `initialState` instead of `count: 0` then? Corrected my answer, please check it out.

Comment: i tried this and it worked     const Context = React.createContext<ContextType>({
      state: initialState,
      actions,
    });
THNX very muuch